# How to receive AURORA NEAR on Ledger

Tags: ledger-nano-s, near

Someone owes me some [AURORA](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/aurora-near/).

I want to receive it on my Ledger Nano X.

So I created an Ethereum account on my device and sent the Ethereum account address to the person who wants to send me tokens.

The person sent a small test transaction, visible at https://explorer.aurora.dev/tx/0x.....

But in my Ledger Live, my Ethereum account says "No crypto assets yet?"

And my account at https://etherscan.io/address/0x..... also does not show any transactions.

But the https://explorer.aurora.dev/tx/0x..... page shows the correct Ethereum account address as recipient.

What have I misunderstood about how to receive AURORA tokens?

P.S. I've omitted the account ID and transaction ID from the URLs above intentionally.

Comment: Account IDs and transaction IDs are public stuff. You can share them (and we will most likely need them to help you).

Comment: It seems Aurora is different blockchain, so you won't the transaction in etherscan.io because it only tracks Ethereum mainnet. You have to ask the other person how you will access the funds on the Aurora blockchain. Likely you'll need a wallet that supports it.

Comment: @Itération122442 Account IDs are public, but the association of a given Account ID to my identity here is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your Ledger to a Metamask Wallet. Then click the Ethereum Mainnet Dropdown menu to "Add network". "
"Add a network manually".
Input this info:

https://help.aurora.dev/article/8-add-aurora-to-metamask

Network Name: Aurora

New RPC URL: https://mainnet.aurora.dev

Chain ID: 1313161554

Currency symbol: ETH

Block explorer URL: https://explorer.aurora.dev

If you dont see Aurora in the Assets tab. Add it using the following info:

Token contract address: 0x8BEc47865aDe3B172A928df8f990Bc7f2A3b9f79

Token decimal: 18

Network: Aurora

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It reminded me to post my notes about what I eventually figured out: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/151947/48808 And I think our answers concur. I would have expected this to be documented very prominently on Aurora's website, but I couldn't find it there (or anywhere).

Comment: I believe it is on the Aurora website somewhere. Ill post a comment here once i find it!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to post until now what I finally got working on 2023-05-04.

I think these were the steps (that I haven't found documented anywhere):

1. Create an ETH account on Ledger.

In MetaMask:

2. connect to Ledger.
3. Click Ethereum Mainnet dropdown > Add network.
4. Do NOT choose Aurora Mainnet in that list of popular networks. That entry mentions Block explorer URL https://aurorascan.dev/ (which is defunct) and Network URL https://aurora-mainnet.infura.io
5. Instead, "Add a network manually". At https://help.aurora.dev/article/8-add-aurora-to-metamask I found:

Network Name: Aurora

New RPC URL: https://mainnet.aurora.dev

Chain ID: 1313161554

and I'm *guessing*:

currency symbol: ETH (because it displayed a warning when I tried "AURORA")

block explorer URL: https://explorer.aurora.dev

6. In the Assets tab, you might see ETH and AURORA now. If you don't see AURORA, try "Import tokens":

Token contract address: 0x8BEc47865aDe3B172A928df8f990Bc7f2A3b9f79

Token decimal: 18

Network: Aurora

(I didn't need to do this, but I wonder if my MetaMask had invisibly "remembered" that I'd done it earlier; I can't remember whether I did.)

https://aurora.dev/tokens confirms that 0x8BEc47865aDe3B172A928df8f990Bc7f2A3b9f79 is correct for AURORA but doesn't specify 18 decimals. I don't know where I got that number.